# Django Signals for task plannification

Tags: django, signals

I try to found the best way to manage this issue with Django Signals:

- I created a datamodel with a table ExecutionPlan
- In this table I simply store task to execute at a "startDate" value.
- I would like to be "signaled" when a "execution line" have a "startDate < Now"

I read Django documentation on signals but I didn't found any case where a signal is send for "a data value check", in my case when a startdate is outpassed.

So my question is more methodic than technical:

Do you think that Django Signals is designed for that case ?
Should I design my own event loop ?

Thanks in advance.
Cyril

Comment: Signals are triggered synchronously. If you want to execute scheduled tasks, you need some other solution. But you don't have to create your own event loop. There are lots of options. https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Comment: Thanks Haken ! I follow your link and I discovered Celery and a lot of resources about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cronjob that runs every X minutes (using [django-cron](https://github.com/tivix/django-cron) for example) that checks if now>startDate and starts the task if needed.